# get all html from span with jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

```
<span class="get" attr-one="1" attr-two="2">text1</span>
<span class="get" attr-one="21" attr-two="2">text2</span>
<span class="get" attr-one="31" attr-four="2">text3</span>
<span class="get" attr-one="4" attr-three="2">tex4t</span>
<span class="get" attr-one="15" attr-five="2">text5</span>

<div id="container" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: red"></div>

$('.get').click(function(){
   $('#container').append($(this).html());
})
```

How can i get current object with HTML add append him to other container? In my example this get only content from my span. I would like get all span with atrributes etc.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bvth3/)

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/bvth3/3/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('.get').click(function(){
   $('#container').append($(this).clone());// to append html like with span now it will copy 

})
```

or

```
$('.get').click(function(){
   $('#container').append($(this));// to append  span now it will move   

})
```

see [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/bvth3/3/)

Comment: Code-only answers are not welcome on SO. Please, extend your answer to include a bit of explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.get').click(function(){
   $('#container').append(this.outerHTML);
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Sp23c/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.get').click(function(){
   $('#container').append($(this));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using get(0) to retrieve natural dom element

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bvth3/5/)

```
$('.get').click(function(){
   $('#container').append($(this).get(0));
})
```